# Ionic, Angular - ChangeDetectorRef is undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am importing the ChangeDetectorRef like so:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef , ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

And initializing a change detector in the constructor of my page like so:

```
constructor(
    ...
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  )
```

But when I execute detectChanges() in a callback function:

```
 hardResetCallback(car:Car){
    this.car=car;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```

It says "Can't read property 'detectChanges' of undefined". What could I be missing?

EDIT:

The callback is called from a modal. The modal gets the callback through nav params - in the parent component I call:

```
const resetModal : Modal = this.modal.create('CarConfigurationResetPage', { car: this.car, callback: this.hardResetCallback });
    resetModal.present();
```

And then this is how I get it in the modal:

```
 this.callback=this.navParams.get('callback');
```

I call the callback from the modal in the success method of an AJAX call like this:

```
this.callback(response);
```

Comment: How and when do you call `hardResetCallback()`?

Comment: Amit - see edit

Comment: So I understood that the "this" variable in the callback refers to the modal, not the parent component. How can I refer the parent component in the callback?

Comment: why don't you bind ``this`` to your  ``this.modal.create() ``?

Comment: Try that `const resetModal : Modal = this.modal.create('CarConfigurationResetPage', { car: this.car, callback: (car) => this.hardResetCallback(car) });`

Comment: Ok, not the error is gone, but the view is not updating as expected. Is there a better way to pass the callback to the modal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 hardResetCallback = (car:Car) => {
    this.car=car;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```

Use fat arrow function to prevent creation of “this” inside the scope of your hardResetCallback method.

See more about arrow functions [here.](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26)

Relevant quote:

> "In classic function expressions, the this keyword is bound to
>   different values based on the context in which it is called. With
>   arrow functions however, this is lexically bound. It means that it
>   uses this from the code that contains the arrow function."

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you explain why the fat arrow or lack thereof changes the context of `this`?

Comment: @CoreCreatives arrow functions by their design do not create their own scope which 'this' would point to. Here is great article I read some time ago: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26. And here is a quote that explains it nicely: "In classic function expressions, the this keyword is bound to different values based on the context in which it is called. With arrow functions however, this is lexically bound. It means that it usesthis from the code that contains the arrow function."

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
this.ref.markForCheck();
if (!this.ref['destroyed']) {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: I renamed `cd` to `ref`, because in question `ref` refferes to `ChangeDetectorRef`. Consider adding explanation why this code would solve issue